# Fade in tableView when data has loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app, I have a list which pushes in a view containing a `UITableView`.

- The background colour of the tableView is always a bold colour, but it is dependant on the selection from the previous view.
- The tableView loads data from an api.
- When the data has finished loading, I call `[self.tableView reloadData];` and the data appears, as expected.

The issue I am having is that the screen is a bold colour for a few seconds (depending on internet connection). When the data has loaded, and the tableView reloads, it is not aesthetically pleasing.

I would quite like to animate the reload with a fade like so;

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

However, this causes the following crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete section 1, but there are only 0 sections before the update'
```

Is there a friendly way to animate my tableView once the data has loaded?

**EDIT:**

- I should have added. The number of sections (and rows) in the table is unknown and I will need to replace the numbers in the code (such as `NSRangeMake` with counts). I know for certain that the example I am testing has 3 sections.
- However, when the page loads there are 0 sections (otherwise the user can see the labels and other elements in the table before it is populated with data).

Comment: `NSMakeRange(0, 1)`. And you may need to ensure that `numberOfSections...` returns 1 both before and after.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView reloadSections:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: `reloadSections` takes an `NSIndexSet` not an `NSIndexPath`